# Dynamically adding panel in the middle of a titlebar

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a panel with a titlebar which already have a two buttons, one on the left and another on the right of the bar. Now I would like to know how to add a panel (or else) to the center of the bar.

**This panel need to have a picture and se string inside.**

This is what I do for the moment but the panel is displayed on the right of the left button and I can't figure out how to put it in the middle of the titlebar.

```
this.getTitlebar().add([{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout:'hbox',
    items:[{
      xtype:'img',
      width:32,
      height:32,
      src:data.image.small.url
    },{
      html: data.key,
      style:'color:#FFF'
    }]
}]);
```

**[UPDATE] : centered: true**

I tried to add centered: true to my panel config but it didn't work, it actually got worse

from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to achieve the same thing, don't use a `Ext.Titlebar` but use a `Ext.Toolbar` instead.

Things like `{xtype:'spacer'}` don't work in Titlebars...

Comment: Yes, if your not specifying a title in your titlebar you should just use a toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

don not need to add the "spacer"

```
items: [
    // your_first_button(default:left)
    {},
    // your_central_panel
    {centered: true},
    // your_second_button
    {right: 0}
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To align your items as described, simply use this prototype:

```
items: [
  {your_first_button},
  {xtype: 'spacer'},
  {your_central_panel},
  {xtpye: 'spacer'},
  {your_second_button},
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have my two buttons when I want to add the panel. How can I add it dynamically in the center ?

Comment: try adding `centered: true` config to your panel, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try insert method of the component?

You can have something like this

```
yourComponent.insert(index,componentTobeAdded);
```

And after adding it, call the component layout of the Toolbar to show the panel added.

Comment: yes, I tried it with indexes from 0 to 4 but it doesn't change anything. btw: you wrote add() in your post. And I'm using ST2, so there is no doComponentLayout() anymore I think if it is what you meant

Comment: so you mean that you are able to add the panel in between of two left and right buttons but it is not centered?

Comment: i can say that you can have something like this, dont know whether this can be solution or a patch.

Instead of having that panel directly at the position, add a Container with style of 100% and -webkit-box-align:center , -webkit-box-pack-center
And add the main panel that you wanted centered to this container you just created.

Now add the first container we created with style to the toolbar.